# Important! Is there a term for misusing the pronoun “you”?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, personal-pronouns

This is somewhat challenging to describe but I’m taking a crack at it. I have the tendency to use the pronoun “you” when speaking to someone about an event, or story. I would almost describe it as a form of dramatics within my storytelling - and the only place I have really observed it is on reality television. Quite often the cast members on these shows will be recounting situations or events to another friend, after the fact, and it almost seems like a production tactic to get more sound bites. But it’s something that people do, including myself.

An example for clarity:

Mary: “Did John end up calling?”
JENN: “No. I can’t believe him. Like why would you plan dinner with me when you’re on a juice cleanse?”

JENN is clearly talking about John, but uses you for dramatic effect. If her delivery is intense or seemingly angry (presumably at John) Mary may mistake this misused “you”
as being directed at her.

I’ve searched high and low, asked every person I know and nobody seems to know the term or word for this type of conversational misuse of grammar. Please, please share your thoughts!

Comment: Who says it’s misuse?

Comment: "Important"? Sure. This is a pretty normal use of "you", certainly not limited to or originating with reality TV. Why do you think it is misuse?

Comment: The meaning is "Why would one (a hypothetical person) plan dinner...?", but using _one_ sounds rather pretentious, so people often substitute _you_. Jenn means 'anyone', not Mary.

Comment: Well, there is the song "The Ram's Lament":  "It had to be ewe 
I wandered around, and I finally found
The somebody who
Could make me be true
And could make me be blue
And even be glad
Just to be sad - thinking of ewe

Comment: No one seems to have the answer. Thanks anyway